# OpenCV: CvBox2D angle

Tags: c++, c, opencv, angle, ellipse

I'm doing some head tracking and I'm trying to estimate the roll angel by useing openCV to fit an ellipse to the head contour. That all works fine and the cvFitEllipse2 returns a CvBox2D. I would like to use the angle of the box to calculate the roll angle, i.e. the angle between the y axis of the image and the long axis of the ellipse.

They say that the box angle is  the angle between the horizonal axis and the first side (i.e length), but the results that I get are somewhat strange.

- The angel is 180° in case my head is upward.
- When I tilt to the right the angle decreases to around 135° normally and then jumps suddenly to around 315°.
- When I tilt to the left the angle rises to around 260° without any strange changes.

Here's short video of this:
[cvBox2D angle](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n0gcxba7id3khbm/cvBox2D%20angle.avi)

Any idea what's going on and how I could calculate the roll angle?

And here is my code:

```
  CvBox2D box;
  CvPoint center;
  CvSize size;
  int count = largest_contour->total;

  CvMat* points_f = cvCreateMat( 1, count, CV_32FC2 );
  CvMat points_i = cvMat( 1, count, CV_32SC2, points_f->data.ptr );
  cvCvtSeqToArray(largest_contour, points_f->data.ptr, CV_WHOLE_SEQ );
  cvConvert( &points_i, points_f );

  box = cvFitEllipse2(points_f);
  center = cvPointFrom32f(box.center);
  size.width = cvRound(box.size.width*0.5);
  size.height = cvRound(box.size.height*0.5);

  cvEllipse(dst,center,size,box.angle,0,360,cvScalar(0,255,0),2,8,0); 

  float newAngle = (box.angle > 90 ? 180 - box.angle : -1*(box.angle));
```

Comment: 315-135=180 so one guess is that you're calculating an arctan function somewhere with 1 parameter of y/x. Is there a 2-parameter arctan function you can use instead, which takes both x and y coordinates, which avoids this inherent 180-degree indeterminacy?

Comment: @Matt I'm not using an arctan function myself anywhere. The source of the cvFitEllipse2 has this somewhere to calculate the angle of the ellipse. I checked the source code and there are two algorithms, both doing some arctan calculations for the angle and I don't get what's actually going on there. But you are right there is this 180° indeterminacy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I have found the answer to my problem.

If you look at the source code for the cvFitEllipse2 function that you can find in ...\modules\imgproc\src  file: "shapedescr.cpp", you will see that there are two different algorithms for doing ellipse fitting. By default only one is used in the openCV231 version I'm using.

icvFitEllipse_F is the function that caused my problem, but there is also a part of the algorithm that is not used because the following statement is in the code of the cvFitEllipse2 function:

```
#if 1
    icvFitEllipse_F( ptseq, &box );
#else
/*
 *  New fitellipse algorithm, contributed by Dr. Daniel Weiss
 */
```

so the new fitellipse algorithm is not compiled.

By changing #if 1 to #if 0  the other algorithm is compiled and used instead of  icvFitEllipse_F and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using CAMShift tracking on several head tracking applications with the calculation below, after simply modifying the CAMShift demo from OpenCV:

float newAngle = (trackBox.angle > 90 ? 180 - trackBox.angle : -1*(trackBox.angle));

If this does not work, please post your code for extracting the roll angle so that we can have a look at the numbers.

Comment: What you have written is on the right track.As far as I see the angle that cvFitEllipse2 gives is between the y axis (that has a "south" direction) and the longer ellipse axis.So your new angle would give me exactly what I need for head tracking.A +/- roll angle.The problem is that the 180° indeterminacy is still there.As Matt said from the arctan calculations,but this is done inside cvFitEllipse2.It happens at two places,when the angle is 45° and when it's -135° (these are angles after adding your code).I updated the video so you can see what I mean and added my code. Hope you can help.

Comment: I also checked CamShift source and I don't see any calls to the fitEllipse. But it calculates the angle of the rectangle and returns this as box.angle. I added above in my post the angle manipulations done in both CamShift and cvFitEllipse2. Maybe you can make some sense of it.

Comment: Since there are angle offsets in all three places, it is possible that we are losing information about the angle at one point. I will try printing angles with my code samples, and get back to you.

Comment: Ok, please do. I would appreciate that very much. Thank you.

Comment: Checked the code, and mine returns angles between -90 and 90. I guess it is not possible to get values beyond 90, because of the symmetry of the fitted ellipse. You can find the code at https://www.dropbox.com/s/ziucjce9xdxnwyz/camShift.pdf 
If you need angles of a larger range, you can a few features of the face, such as eyes and the tip of the nose.

Comment: I'm sorry, I aplogize for not realising this sooner, but I'm working with a grayscale image. I'm using a TOF camera and I can only get a grayscale image from it. Since the CamShift works on color images, I doubt that it is the way to go. I have however found a solution and wrote it as an answer to my own question. Thank you for trying to help anyway.

Comment: No worries, and thanks for posting the answer. Not sure which one is compiled in the newer versions of OpenCV, that's worth checking.